# Filter IEnumerable<T> based on IEnumerable,String>

Tags: c#, linq, collections, ienumerable

Hi There I Have the following code and the issues is i want to so a select or a where based on a filter but the filter is a IEnumerable I am missing the linq to complete the query. I want all the classB's where the ClassB.MyType is contained in the filter. Thanks in advance

```
 public class EntryPoint
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClassB> FilterClass(IEnumerable<string> filter)
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass(); // populate with values

            return myClass.Values.Where(x => x.MyType == filter//??));
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public IEnumerable<ClassB> Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public string MyType { get; set; }

        public string MyValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
return myClass.Values.Where(x => filter.Contains(x.MyType));
```

This, however, may compare for referential equality - also consider the following alternative

```
return myClass.Values.Where(x => filter.Any(f => x.MyType.Equals(f)));
```

Comment: pipped me to the post

Answer (score 0):

Surely something like

```
return myClass.Values.Where(x => filter.Any(f => f == x.MyType));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return myClass.Values.Where(x =>filter.Contains(x.MyType));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i think i want to go for the r referential equality!